# Как сделать чтобы qgraphicsview динамически менял свой размер под окно?

Tags: c++, qt5

Есть qgraphicsview и надо чтобы он растягивался автоматически под пространство окна. Какие есть способы для реализации этого?

Comment: в окне переопределяете метод resizeEvent и меняете там размер вьюшки

Comment: Нажмите в дизайнере в свободном от виджета месте формы правой кнопкой мыши и выберите Компоновщик - Скомпоновать по сетке.

Comment: Добавьте qgraphicsview на компоновщик (layout), компоновщик должен быть на виджете-окне. Кст, через дизайнер сделали форму или в коде?